# Is autowiring conflicts the spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring

I am bit confused about the autowiring and spring dependency injection.

spring dependency injection enables you to remove any specific dependencies
a class may have on other classes or third party interfaces, and load these dependencies into the class at construction time.

But while using Autowired annotation, we are programmatically writing the interface name or the class name in the java class to inject bean.

```
@Autowired
public final Interface object;
```

Is this not conflicting the spring dependency injection? Because if we are defining bean in XML we can change it anytime without changing the actual java code. But using annotation we have to change the java code.

Comment: "enables you to remove any specific dependencies a class may have on other classes or third party interfaces": No. You remove dependencies on concrete implementations, meaning it could be any subtype of what you autowire. Exactly the same as with XML config (the only difference is the lack of the `@Autowired` annotation in your code).

Comment: @Autowired (technically called Component scan) and old style XML configuration are the same result. So you should only use one thing. Choose wisely depend on your application type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dependency injection Spring requires at least a contract ( Java Interface ) in the class and you can dynamically switch implementation at runtime with XML or Java Based annotation. Even if it is done through XML we need to provide the Interface with constructors so wiring the bean automatically needs that interface class variable too.

But as you told, to put Java based Annotation we need to have the access to the Source code and this is a kind of main drawback with Annotation. This comes for AOP too. To make a class an Aspect you need to have the source code access.